# Need to integrate phpFox and Wordpress so that there is a single login

Tags: php, wordpress

phpFox should take care of user login management, add user and edit user. But would like to automatically create a corresponding Wordpress account when user signs up for phpFox. And when user logs into phpFox user is auto logged into Wordpress so user doesn't really even realize Wordpress login or user account exists.

What would be the best way to do this?

Apps will be on the same server so could make native calls or use curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up doing this by automatically creating a WP user (using jquery ajax call) when phpFox user was created. And then when phpFox user logged in use jquery again to post to the WP login form.